# Notification makes sound but does not display anything

Tags: ios, swift

For my app I am looking to implement a local notification system.

My code to schedule a notification is as follows:

```
func scheduleNotification(_ Name:String, _ Time:DateComponents){
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        let notification = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        notification.title = Name
        notification.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()


        var trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: Time, repeats: false)

        let identifier = Name

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: notification, trigger: trigger)
        center.add(request)

    }
```

Now that worked yesterday, but not it no longer does. In both simulator and device.

I've tried the suggestion here to no avail: [Local Notifications make sound but do not display (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42431171/local-notifications-make-sound-but-do-not-display-swift)

What I have tried:

- Testing with the app force closed
- Testing with the app in the background
- Changing identifiers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to set `body` of notification. add this line too below `notification.title = Name` line

```
notification.body = "Hello Notification"
```

For more check [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter).

Comment: I have received local notification but after 5 seconds automatically dismiss the notification popup, if any body give the suggestion to stay the popup more than 5 seconds?